# How to clear SmartForm value?

Tags: sapui5

I have a SmartForm that looks as following:

```
<Dialog id="massChangeDialog" title="{i18n>ChangeMaintainanceOrderOperation}" resizable="true" draggable="true" contentWidth="900px"
    contentHeight="700px">
    <content>
        <smartForm:SmartForm id="editOperation" editable="true" entityType="EditOperation">
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{WorkCenter}" id="idWorkCenter" width="90%" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{PersonalNumber}" id="idPersonalNr" width="90%"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{ActionDescription}" width="90%" id="idDispatch"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{ChangedDate}" id="idDate" width="90%"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{ChangedTime}" id="idTime" width="90%" placeholder="{i18n>EnterTime}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
        </smartForm:SmartForm>
    </content>
</Dialog>
```

The dialog context is bound to a odata service:

```
if (!this.oDialogChangeOperations) {
    // Begin of 0001
    this.oDialogChangeOperations = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(),
        "rsh.eam.details1.RSH_EAM_DETS1Extension.view.ChangeOperationsCustom", this);
    // End of 0001
    //this.getView().addDependent(this.oDialogChangeOperations);
    this.oDialogChangeOperations.setModel(this.getModel("EditOp"));

    this.byId("MassChange").attachPress(this.onMassChangePressed, this);
    this.byId("CloseDialog").attachPress(this.onCloseDialog, this);
    this.byId("RestChange").attachPress(this.onResetMassChangePressed, this);

}
```

The model `this.getModel("EditOp")` is a odata service.

The UI looks as following:

[image]

As you can see on the image, the **PersonalNo.** is filled with value. How can I delete the value, if the user pressed the **reset** button?

I tried with:

```
this.byId("idPersonalNr").setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
this.byId("idPersonalNr").setValue('0');
```

and

```
this.oDialogChangeOperations.getModel().setProperty("/PersonalNumber", this.intialPerson);
                this.oDialogChangeOperations.getModel().refresh();
```

and it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setData` method of the model to set values.

Here's an example I created for you in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/gabogiruqo/edit?html,output).

The JSON Model in the example has 2 properties `PersonnelNo` and `OtherInfo` bound to `sap.m.Input` controls. Clicking the `Reset` button, I do the following,

```
oJsonModel.setData({PersonnelNo:null},true);
```

The `PersonnelNo` is cleared and the `OtherInfo` property is untouched due to the `true` value towards the end of the method, meaning the changes are merged into the model instead of re-writing the enter model data. You can also set multiple values at the same time.

[SAPUI5 JSON Model setData API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel/methods/setData)

Comment: It is not a JSON Model, it is a https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.

Answer (score 0):

Approaches I have found that works with smartFroms in Dialogs are:

1. if you have set binding for the element - use `.unbindElement()`. Of course that would mean you have to bind it again when needed.
2. as it is oData Model `.resetChanges()` on the Model can be used. You can indicate also paths that should be reset as a parameter.

Hope it helps,
Shanir